# Usando o Access para exporta no Excel, Query Parametrizada

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

Estou usando o banco de dados o Access, preciso exportar uma query para o excel.

Meu problema está sendo o seguinte:

Estou usando uma query parametrizada no Access para o próprio access exportar para o excel.

Quando faco a chamada para exportar, abre a tela para digitar o parametro. 
Queria passar esse parametro via codigo)

```
 private void btnExportarParaExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Salvar Arquivo";
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel|.xlsx";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 0;
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "Match_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
        saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @frmPrincipal.caminhoDoSistema;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        DialogResult resultado = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (resultado == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            String mesAno = frmPrincipal.mesAno;
            mesAno = mesAno.Substring(3, 4) + mesAno.Substring(0, 2);
            var accessApp = new Access.Application();
            try
            {
                accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(@frmPrincipal.caminhoDoSistema + @"\Database\" + mesAno + @"\prjRecon.accdb", false);
                accessApp.DoCmd.SetParameter("companhia", frmPrincipal.companhia);
                accessApp.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet(Access.AcDataTransferType.acExport, Access.AcSpreadSheetType.acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Match_LancamentosContabeis2", @saveFileDialog1.FileName);
                MessageBox.Show("Arquivo salvo com sucesso!", "Sucesso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (COMException ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Erro:" + "\n" + ex.ToString());
            }
            accessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase();
            accessApp.Quit();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Operação cancelada");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tela pra digitar qual parâmetro?

Comment: Por exemplo essa tela:
http://assets.gcflearnfree.org/topics/177/x_parameter_whatdatemmddyy.png

Comment: Legal a tela. Mas onde ela se encaixa no seu exemplo?

Comment: `accessApp.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet(Access.AcDataTransferType.acExport, Access.AcSpreadSheetType.acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Match_LancamentosContabeis2", @saveFileDialog1.FileName);`

Quando passo este comando, para exportar a query pro excel, aparece a tela para inserir o parametro.

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais prática seria usar variáveis temporárias.

Tente o seguinte:

1. Tomando como base que a sua consulta use algo parecido com a [imagem](http://assets.gcflearnfree.org/topics/177/x_parameter_whatdatemmddyy.png) que você mandou. Altere o critério `[What Date? (dd/mm/yy)]` para `[TempVars]![MeuCriterio]`
2. No seu código inclua seguinte linha `TempVars.Add "MeuCriterio", valor_do_seu_criterio`

Dessa forma, poderá passar o critério via código para a consulta e não terá que preencher a janela durante o tempo de execução.